# jQuery: bind two events

Tags: jquery

I have a div called MyDiv. How do I call 2 functions one after the other when the user clicks it?

```
$('#MyDiv').click(function () {
    action1() // wait until it finishes and call action2
});
```

`action1` is a function in a script that's loaded in my master page and `action2` is a small inline script function that's different in every page which means I can't call `action2` from `action1` because the name `action2` will actually be different on every page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If action1 and action2 aren't asynchonous, you can just do:

```
$('#MyDiv').click(function () { action1(); action2() });
```

If they are asynchonous, you can do a couple of things. Callbacks:

```
action1 = function(callback) {
  //stuff
  callback();
}
$('#MyDiv').click(function () { action1(this) });
```

Note you're not calling action2 when you pass it. Just passing the function.

You could also fire an event from action1 and tell action2 to listen for that event (working from memory here):

```
action1 = function(element) {
  //stuff
  $(element).trigger('action1_finished')
}
$('#MyDiv').click(function () { action1(this) }).bind('action1_finished', action2)
```

Comment: In my case, I want to run action2 after action1 finishes; is this called synchronous or asynchronous? Will option 1 fire both functions simultaneously?

Comment: +1 for chaining custom events.
@frenchie, I assume `action1` has an animation (or async something or other)? you'll need to trigger the event when `action1` has completed, but it's the best way to do it in an event-oriented language like JS

Comment: If you're using jQuery to do the animation, I think the newer version has a callback option. In your case, it might be like:

    .animate({/*new properties*/}, {complete: action2();}

Check http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Answer (score 1):

Javascript functions are synchronous.
You can just call `action2` after `action1`, and it will run after `action1` finishes.

If `action1` is asynchronous (if it does AJAX or animation), you'll need to make it take a callback parameter.